# Visual Studio Team System switching opinions

Tags: development-environment

Assume your .NET-based development team is already using the following set of tools in its processes:

- Subversion / TortoiseSVN / VisualSVN (source control)
- NUnit (unit testing)
- An open source Wiki
- A proprietary bug-tracking system that is paid for

You are happy with Subversion and NUnit, but dislike the Wiki and bug-tracking system.  You also would like to add some lightweight project-management software (like Fogbugz/Trac) - it does not have to be free, but obviously cheaper is better.

Can you make a compelling argument for adopting VSTS, either to add missing features and replace disliked software or to handle everything (including the source control)?  Is the integration of all these features greater than the sum of the parts, or would it simply be better to acquire and replace the parts that you either do not like or do not have?

I remember looking into VSTS a few years ago and thought it was terribly expensive and not really better than many of the free options, but I assume Microsoft has continued to work on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSTS is great, if you do everything in it. Unfortunately the price has not become better over the years. :( The CAL's are still ludicrously expensive. The only improvement is that if a person uses **only** the work item system, and works **only** with his/her own work items (no peeking at other person's work items!) then there is no need for a CAL. This makes it a bit easier to use it as an external bugreport system. Still it leaves a lot to be desired in this area.

There is one way to alleviate the cost - become Microsoft Certified Partner. If you are a simple partner, you get 5 VS/TFS licenses for free; if you are a Gold Certifiend Partner, you get 25 (if memory fails me not). That should be enough for most companies. But getting the Gold status might be tricky, depending on what you do.

If you only dislike those two parts, then perhaps it's better just to find a replacement for them instead for everything? There are many wiki systems out there, some should be to your liking. The same goes for bugtracking too.

Answer (score 2):

We are extremely happy with not only the tools, but the integration that Team Foundation Server, and the various Team Editions have given us.  We previously used Borland's StarTeam for source control and issue tracking with a 3rd party wiki, the name of which escapes me at the moment.

It came time for us to extend our licensing and support agreement with Borland, only to learn that the cost of adding users to our license and upgrading the product would cost us as much (a little more, actually) than biting the bullet and making the switch.  One thing to consider is that you would normally pay for the development tools to begin with, so the cost is partially absorbed by our budget.

We also did not feel the need for getting Team Suite for every person.  You might want to consider it for the developers, but other disciplines don't really have a benefit in using all of the tools in most companies.

We were able to get the appropriate team editions for twelve people, enough CALs for 50 users (for Team Explorer, Teamprise, Team Project Portals, Team Web Access), Teamprise for the five Mac Users that we have, and the Team Foundation Server software itself for under six figures.  Considering that includes the developer tools that we normally would be buying, it was a good deal.

The upfront cost on new licensing also covered two years, so we could split the budget between the 2008 and 2009 fiscal years.  The very important thing is to make sure not to let the licenses lapse, as the renewals on licenses cost a fraction of the initial cost and also include version upgrades.

As to the features, we are in the process of rolling out.  About half of our department completed training, and I have already started migrating projects over.  The development team absolutely loves the features and tight integration with their workflow.  Version control is a snap, and work items (and their related reporting artifacts) are extensible to the nth degree.  The fact that TFS relies heavily on bringing sanity to workflow management helps to tie in all of the processes to a level that you just can not get with multiple vendors.

My absolute favorite thing, though, is the extensibility model.  Using the Team Foundation Server API, you can easily write check-in policies, write tools to interface with the system, develop plug-ins, and more.  We are already seeing gains in productivity and the quality of our products through a minimal implementation.

Still on the horizon, though, is integrating Team Build.  I have yet to set up a build project, but it seems to be seamless and painless.  Time will tell...  :-)

**Edit - I forgot to mention that our migration to TFS includes licensing for the Test Load Agent.  The load testing functionality within Team Test is one of, if not the absolute best that I have seen.**

Comment: Sounds really powerful, though I am afraid it might be too complex for our usage.  Would it make sense for a small team, say around 10 developers and a few testers?  Thanks for the detailed input!

Answer (score 1):

Where I'm at, we've settled on the following:

- SVN for source control
- [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) for bug-tracking and wiki
- NUnit for unit testing
- CruiseControl.NET for our build server

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) is an open source Ruby on Rails application that supports multiple projects much better than Trac and seems to be much easier to administer. It's definitely worth checking out.

VSTS seems to be way too much money compared to other products. As an additional benefit, you also get the souce with open source solutions, which allows you to modify things to fit your need if the capability isn't there yet.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Redmine, I had never heard of it before.

Answer (score 0):

I'd stick with SVN and use trac or bugzilla or fogbugz.  You could also do a trial of team server.  In my opinion it is not worth the money.  MS had their chance with version control and they screwed it up a long time ago.  Too late to the party if you ask me and frankly I am not impressed with how they try to control all your development experience in the IDE with "integration" to the source control.  I prefer the perforce/SVN and separate defect tracking solution.

With all that said, you probably can't go wrong with any of the following:

bugzilla or trac or fogbugz AND SVN
MS team thingamabob